# Как с помощью hover скрыть одну иконку и показать другую иконку?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, svg, hover

У меня есть небольшая проблемка, и я надеюсь что здесь мне помогут её решить.
Скорее всего проблема не сложная, но уже несколько часов не могу понять как всё должно работать.
В общем, суть в чем. Мне потребовался шестиугольник, внутри которого шестиугольник по меньше и внутри которого картинка в формате svg. При наведении она должна менять свой background на белый цвет, и картинку на другую.
Через hover сделал смену фона, но никак не пойму, как спрятать первую картинку и показать вторую во время срабатывания hover.

[image: Такая она должна быть.]
[image: А так должна выглядеть При срабатывании hover.]

Comment: точно так же как ты меняешь цвет, только нужно менять display у картинок

Answer (score 3):

Для начала найдём эту иконку,  пишем в yandex/google так: **ракета svg icon**

Видим в вот такую ссылку: https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/rocket

Переходим и скачиваем эту иконку и так же скачиваем векторный редактор [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/ru/release/inkscape-1.0/)

После того как скачали программу и установили то открываем скачанную иконку в этой программе, дорисовываем рамку и сохраняем в удобном месте ...

После чего действуют такие же правила как и в css - смотрим результат

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 9px;
  transition: 0.34s linear;
}

g path {
  fill: #000;
  stroke-width: 0;
}

svg:hover g>path {
  fill: #fff;
}

svg:hover path {
  fill: tomato;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 304.13 335.39" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100">
    
  <path d="m3.7976 89.994 152.06-84.615 144.49 78.632-1.1119 173.42-143.37 74.77-151.9-75.93z" />
    <g>
   <path d="m261.91 92.303c-0.46313-7.5246-7.218-13.508-15.711-13.919-17.138-0.82949-50.674-0.02257-82.741 14.672-16.347 7.4913-33.637 20.192-47.434 34.846-0.16997 0.18055-0.33534 0.3622-0.50406 0.54312l-31.313 2.1429c-5.1542 0.35296-9.745 2.7463-12.596 6.566l-21.363 28.626c-2.162 2.8969-2.5057 6.5223-0.91999 9.6978 1.5861 3.1759 4.8451 5.3891 8.7185 5.9207l26.381 3.6198c-0.0931 0.45433-0.18667 0.90829-0.27228 1.3626-0.87824 4.6543 0.86236 9.4396 4.6568 12.801l36.746 32.555c3.1459 2.787 7.3967 4.3235 11.752 4.3235 0.89703 0 1.7991-0.0655 2.6969-0.19831 0.51282-0.0759 1.0252-0.15872 1.5381-0.24123l4.0859 23.372c0.60011 3.4315 3.0983 6.3192 6.6822 7.724 1.4913 0.58456 3.0694 0.87314 4.6405 0.87314 2.2062-3.7e-4 4.397-0.56939 6.3064-1.6878l32.311-18.926c4.3118-2.5258 7.013-6.593 7.4105-11.159l2.4188-27.74c0.20421-0.14947 0.40968-0.29598 0.61347-0.44656 16.541-12.224 30.878-27.541 39.333-42.024 16.587-28.411 17.496-58.122 16.561-73.304zm-73.247 145.41-30.908 18.104-3.9824-22.778c13.063-3.4027 25.985-8.8524 38.296-16.153l-1.5756 18.071c-0.0981 1.1273-0.76548 2.1318-1.83 2.7552zm-54.246-13.829-36.747-32.555c-0.93754-0.83096-1.371-1.9982-1.1584-3.1226 1.0925-5.7875 2.7901-11.297 4.8915-16.487l55.136 48.847c-7.0359 2.2328-13.338 3.5647-18.598 4.3439-1.2712 0.18721-2.5871-0.19571-3.5246-1.0263zm-49.246-82.234 20.398-1.3959c-8.2412 10.907-14.393 22.355-18.233 33.928l-25.71-3.5277 20.435-27.383c0.70409-0.94344 1.8379-1.5343 3.11-1.6212zm112.82 57.452c-10.12 7.4783-19.943 12.887-28.998 16.801l-62.316-55.208c5.7873-10.472 12.85-19.192 18.967-25.688 12.768-13.561 28.649-25.26 43.57-32.098 29.431-13.487 60.439-14.213 76.303-13.448 2.0998 0.10137 3.7698 1.5809 3.8842 3.4415 0.86487 14.055 0.0434 41.525-15.18 67.599-7.717 13.218-20.922 27.287-36.229 38.599z"/>
   <path d="m194.81 165.57c8.019-7.4e-4 16.041-2.7053 22.146-8.1139 5.9159-5.2407 9.1733-12.209 9.1733-19.62s-3.2578-14.379-9.1733-19.62c-12.212-10.819-32.082-10.818-44.293 0-5.9159 5.2407-9.1737 12.209-9.1737 19.62s3.2582 14.379 9.1737 19.62c6.1063 5.4098 14.124 8.1147 22.146 8.1139zm-13.288-39.506c3.6633-3.2458 8.4754-4.8685 13.288-4.8685 4.8126 0 9.6247 1.6227 13.288 4.8685 3.5493 3.1444 5.5037 7.3252 5.5037 11.772s-1.9544 8.6278-5.5037 11.772c-7.3266 6.4912-19.249 6.4909-26.576 0-3.5493-3.1444-5.5041-7.3252-5.5041-11.772s1.9553-8.6278 5.5045-11.772z"/>
   <path d="m54.736 234.27c1.6032 0 3.2064-0.54164 4.4292-1.6257l20.452-18.119c2.4464-2.1673 2.4464-5.681 0-7.8483-2.446-2.1673-6.4124-2.1673-8.8588 0l-20.451 18.119c-2.4464 2.1673-2.4464 5.681 0 7.8483 1.2228 1.0837 2.826 1.6257 4.4292 1.6257z"/>
   <path d="m98.36 223.28c-2.446-2.1673-6.4124-2.1673-8.8588 0l-39.32 34.835c-2.4464 2.1673-2.4464 5.681 0 7.8483 1.2232 1.0837 2.826 1.6253 4.4292 1.6253 1.6032 0 3.2064-0.54164 4.4292-1.6257l39.32-34.835c2.4468-2.1673 2.4468-5.681 4.2e-4 -7.8483z"/>
   <path d="m108.24 239.89-20.452 18.119c-2.4464 2.1673-2.4464 5.681 0 7.8483 1.2232 1.0837 2.8264 1.6257 4.4292 1.6257 1.6028 0 3.2064-0.54165 4.4292-1.6257l20.452-18.119c2.4464-2.1673 2.4464-5.681 0-7.8483-2.446-2.1673-6.4124-2.1673-8.8584 0z"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Если вдруг по теме svg станет не ясно то можно почитать описание всех свойств на сайте разработчика программного обеспечения [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)